# providing vpc end point in aws api gateway cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am not finding any details on how I can add vpc end points in my cloud formation for api gateway.
This is my cfn template, I can provide endpointconfiguration as Private but I can't seem to add vpce details. I can update api through console but I want it to be updated through cloud formation.

```
"TestApi": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
  "Properties": {
      "StageName": {"Ref": "ApiStageName"},
      "EndpointConfiguration": "PRIVATE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [EndpointConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-endpointconfiguration.html) has the form of:

```
  Type: String
  VPCEndpointIds: List
```

So using `VPCEndpointIds` you can provide the VPC interface endpoints IDs for your private API.

Comment: These are the errors I am getting when instead of provided a string value of "REGIONAL", "EDGE", or "PRIVATE", I try to provide type and VpcEndPointIds in my serverless.template.
VpcEndpointIds key is invalid for this object, Type key is invalid for this object, any ideas?

Comment: @SaminSiddiqui What I provided is correct syntax for `"AWS::Serverless::Api` which you use as I linked to AWS docs. You must be doing something wrong, which are are not showing in your question.